# Is it possible to force and stay on automatic calculation on Excel with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm sending an Excel workbook to users where I need automatic calculation to be always activated.

The problem is that I can't prevent users to put on manual calculation once they have the file.

The idea I had was to put on automatic calculation each time the user click somewhere in the workbook.

I tried to solve the problem with VBA and a workbook_activate macro :

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
End Sub
```

It worked a time but now it seems that it doesn't work anymore.

Do you know what I can do to solve my problem ?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work anymore"? It should work in any conditions. Maybe the user, after setting the manual calculation, commented the above code, too... Did you check this aspect?

Comment: Is the value `xlAutomatic` correct, or should it be `xlCalculationAutomatic`?

Comment: try Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.CalculateFull

Comment: @FaneDuru I tried it by my own so the problem isn't coming from the users

Comment: @virxen and Shrotter, thanks for the help but it does'nt work as I wanted to. I've edited my post to explain more clearly what i would like to do. The idea was to put on automatic calculation each time the user click somewhere in the workbook. But I don't know if this is possible...

Comment: *I can't prevent users to put on manual calculation once they have the file* There is no way you can do this in a 100% secure way. Besides, if they do it maybe they need it for something. Even if you code something to activate it every time they click somewhere, they can get rid of the code easily. Best solution is, indeed, talk to them.

Answer (score 0):

Foxfire's comments are perfectly valid. This should be approached as a training issue, rather than a technical change. However, there's nothing wrong with trying to do both to increase security. You could even alter the code to detect when a user has switched off autocalc and warn them this is against best practise.

> The idea was to put on automatic calculation each time the user click somewhere in the workbook. But I don't know if this is possible...

You could use the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event and that would give you exactly that. However, you'd have to put this in each of the worksheets.

A slightly better approach might be to only run when a change is made - after all, only a change should require a recalc. This can be done at a Workbook level like so:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

An alternative version - with a warning:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Application.Calculation <> xlCalculationAutomatic Then
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        MsgBox "Please do not disable automatic calculation blah blah blah.."
    End If
End Sub
```